# Jasper Sub Report in Eclipse

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm new in creating Jasper Reports.
Recently, I create a simple report with a subreport inside. However, I faced some problems when running the report by using tomcat and Eclipse, while I successfully showed all the details of subreport in the mainreport under preview mode. I believe that I have missed some settings in my report.

Here is the error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Resource not found at : SubReport.jasper
at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getResourceFromLocation(RepositoryUtil.java:255)
at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getReport(RepositoryUtil.java:208)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateReport(JRFillSubreport.java:329)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:359)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluate(JRFillSubreport.java:287)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:257)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:457)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2037)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:771)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:281)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:144)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:909)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:822)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:61)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:849)
at org.apache.jsp.GenerateReport_jsp._jspService(GenerateReport_jsp.java:87)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

AND here is my JSP code

```
<%@ page contentType="application/pdf"%>
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>
<%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.FileInputStream"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.FileNotFoundException"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.InputStream"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>

<%
    Connection conn = null;
    Map parametersMap = new HashMap();  
    parametersMap.put("id",1);
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project?user=root&password=123456");

        String jrxmlFile = session.getServletContext().getRealPath("MainReport.jrxml");
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(jrxmlFile));

        //Generation the report
        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(input);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parametersMap, conn);

        //Exporting the report as PDF
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, response.getOutputStream());
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
        response.getOutputStream().close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(conn != null){
            conn.close();
        }
    }
%>
```

Comment: You should pass subreport to main report. You can look at [Subreport Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/subreport/index.html#subreports)

Comment: Thanks for the example provided. However, I don't really understand the source code of jasper report. Is there any other way of passing it to the main report?